# Opening Hik-Connect using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, package, classname

I am using below code to open the app named : **Hik-Connect** as below :

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setClassName("com.hikvision.hikconnect",
                    "CLASS NAME NEEDS TO PASS");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "GIT Cameras");
            startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

You can see am using the package name : **com.hikvision.hikconnect**.

What I have to pass as class name ?

Please guide me. How can I open this application using Intent in Android ?

The app link is as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hikvision.hikconnect&hl=en_IN

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyone who can guide ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getLaunchIntentForPackage` with target app's package name and `resolveActivity`, so you won't get ActivityNotFoundException -

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.hikvision.hikconnect");

if(intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null){  //Open Hik-Connect app if installed
    startActivity(intent);
}else { 
//show toast or handle however you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without class name.
PackageManager has a method called getLaunchIntentForPackage()

[getLaunchIntentForPackage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String))

```
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.hikvision.hikconnect")
startActivity(launchIntent)
```